# Why is my print getting messed up mid-print?

Tags: filament, pla, print-quality, slic3r, marlin

I am using Slic3r to generate the GCode for my Marlin-based printer. For some reason with increasing height my print starts to get messed up. On another part it starts to act like this when there are small parts. Is this related to my Slic3r settings, maybe to much filament being extruded or is this due to something else?

Any help is highly appreciated and I can provide more pictures of messed up parts or slic3r config if necessary.

[image: The filament is completely messed up]

[image: Another picture of the messed up print]

Comment: Can you please upload another image, it's hard to see what might have happened. From the current picture, it looks like the part was set on fire lol

Comment: @tbm0115 Just added another picture of a different part. It's hard to make the camera focus on the messed up part. I am printing the same part again with less infill right now to make sure it's not an overextrusion.

Comment: I can help you out if you provide the printing and the model of our printer. I have my own 3D printing company with 2 years of experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, this looks like a combination of bad filament, high temperature and/or fast speeds.

- Too high extrusion temperature will make difficult to let each layer cool enough before the next layer begins. This is why you see the poor results on the smaller areas of the print in your second photo.
- If you're using bad filament (out of round, non-virgin, or poorly stored filament) you might see a series of over/under extrusion areas or smoke from moisture in the filament.
- Slowing down your feed rates can be tricky if your extrusion temps are too high. By slowing down, you're allowing layers to cool down a little bit more and solidify. If your previous layers are still relatively molten, you'll notice that the new layer of filament will adhere to it and potentially drag the previous layers as the nozzle continues to move. You'll see the results of this in the top-arc layers with an uneven curvature.

Comment: The filament has a constant diameter, I measured using a caliper. I reduced the temperature and also reduced the infill for that part, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this looks like a cooling problem. Try to print this part 2-4 times in one print and get sure your fan is cooling all the time.

It is a known problem, if the layers get smaller, that they do not have time to cool down. So you're printing on a wobbling bunch of still soft layers, which result in what you showed on the photo.

In my opinion, this has nothing to do with the filamen.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your filament is having to be pulled off the spool and slipping in the extruder. Check if slippage is happening at the extruder, perhaps see if results change by providing some hand powered help.  I have seen this with some glossy PLA I have used.

Comment: The filament is not on a spool anymore as I also figured out this could be a problem.